# I want to load a JSON string into a Flexigrid table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, flexigrid

I´m trying to create a table using a mysql resulset into a JSON string. I have the packages needed for Flexigrid and the function to load data fromo another php (table.php) in the same path.

I can show the Flexigrid Table, but no data is shown. When I check the table.php in the browser I get the JSON string and all "looks" correct.
I share my code if anybody can help me to understand what am I missing?

table.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '123';
$db = 'nwind';
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die ('Error!');   
mysql_select_db($db) or die ('Check the Data Base');    
$query = 'SELECT orderId, customerId, employeeId, orderDate FROM orders';
$resultset = mysql_query ($query);  
if (!$resultset) {
$message  = 'Query error: ' . mysql_error() . '\n';
$message .= 'Search: ' . $query;
die($message);
}   
$json = array();
while ($object = mysql_fetch_object($resultset)) {
$json[] = array(
"Order_ID" => $object->orderId,
"Customer_ID" => $object->customerId,
"Employee_ID" => $object->employeeId,
"Order_Date" => $object->orderDate
);
}
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

example.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../flexigrid/css/flexigrid.pack.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../flexigrid/js/flexigrid.pack.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flexigrid">
<table id="flex"></table>
</div>      
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#flex").flexigrid({
url:'table.php',
dataType:'json',
colModel : [
{display: 'Order_ID',
name : 'orderId',
width : 60,
sortable : true,
align: 'center'},
{display: 'Customer_ID',
name : 'customerId',
width : 180,
sortable : true,
align: 'left'},
{display: 'Employee_ID',
name : 'employeeId',
width : 120,
sortable : false,
align: 'left'},
{display: 'Order_Date',
name : 'orderDate',
width : 130,
sortable : true,
align: 'left'}
],
sortname: 'orderId',
sortorder: 'asc',
usepager: true,
title: 'Orders',
useRp: true,
rp: 15,
showTableToggleBtn: true,
width: 700,
height: 200,
resizable: false
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: suggest try matching JSON key to `colModel name` not `display`

Comment: I tried but didn't work.

Comment: [{"orderId":"10248","customerId":"VINET","employeeId":"5","orderDate":"1996-07-04 00:00:00"},{"orderId":"10249","customerId":"TOMSP","employeeId":"6","orderDate":"1996-07-05 00:00:00"},{"orderId":"10250","customerId":"HANAR","employeeId":"4","orderDate":"1996-07-08 00:00:00"},{"orderId":"10251",....
This is how the JSON string looks

Comment: inspect ajax request in browser console to see if i is being made and completed. Is path correct to `table.php`? Console will show what is sent and returned(if any) and status

Comment: Yes in console I got the JSON string and the path seems correct. This is the path and method used "POST http://localhost/sdcr_v2/interfaces/table.php". There are two fields in the send "qtype" and "query", the first is specified with qtype=customerId and the other is blank, is this relevant? The data is recieved, but is not created and shown in the table.

Comment: The code shown below is the complete code (except libraries for flexi and jquery), should I modify something else in my parameters in any file to create the JSON string?

Comment: only other sugestion is remove last column defintiion so number of coulomns of data match # columns in defintiions. AM not familiar with using this plugin...double check that html layout matches demos. Am assuming no erorrs thrown n console?

Comment: Thanks for help, I already found this tuto (http://www.kenthouse.com/blog/2009/07/fun-with-flexigrids/) I´m working on it to check out if really works. Share the link to help others.

Comment: i prefer better documented plugins like datatables.js. More features and well supported, also still developed

Comment: Thanks for help me, the tuto I found was very usefull to learn how to use flexigrid. I was thinking in using datatabes too.

Answer (score 1):

Just check your ColumnModel in javascript. It surely musn't be matching with your returning data.